# Multithread use AutoResetEvent WaitOne independently each threads in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

Hi I have multithread application (c# iis app) .I startted multithread as a background thread.And Inside each thread I have a logic which use autoresetevent.waitone.But as a result when one thread is use waitone command other threads also go to sleep mode and not work.How can I seperate WaitOne logic and not to effect other threads?

```
Thread1 
    AutoResetEvent receiveCompleteEvent=null;
    using(receiveCompleteEvent=new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false))
    {
    DoJob1();...

    receiveCompleteEvent.WaitOne();
    }

Thread2
    AutoResetEvent receiveCompleteEvent=null;
    using(receiveCompleteEvent=new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false))
    {
    DoJob2();...

    receiveCompleteEvent.WaitOne();
    }
```

Thread2 not working when Thread1 works or opposite.
I want when thread1 enter to waitone and go to sleep ,thread2 is still working on to its job independently.

Comment: All threads have their own  AutoResetEvent receiveCompleteEvent,think like receiveCompleteEvent1,receiveCompleteEvent2...

Answer (score 0):

That is because each thread is overwriting the ARE instance from the other one. If you separate wait events then you run into race conditions and there's no synchronization.

So, do you want mutual exclusion **or** do you want race conditions? Your current code manages to achieve both in a manner.

Comment: Hi,I seperate receivecompleteevent and each thread call I create a new one but first thread block other.using (receiveCompleteEvent = new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false))
            {
              //Code was here Dojob
               receiveCompleteEvent.WaitOne();
              
            }Can you share sample code please?

Comment: I want each threads works independently with other.If one thread enter waitone other thread continues its work

Comment: It is not clear why you insist on using ARE if you want threads to proceed independently. Are you looking for a lock-free implementation of something?